# Does updating firmware updates the bios in ubuntu 18?

Tags: updates, update-manager, bios, firmware, fwupd

I am using ubuntu 18 and wish to update both the firmware and the bios. 
Does updating the firmware using [this](https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/) manual and this command 
update the bios as well as the firmware?

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. A BIOS generally will only accept firmware updates from a flashdrive formatted in a specific way and with specific files on it in a specific way, when inside the BIOS menu. I'm pretty sure of this, given my experience updating the BIOS and firmware of some computers.

Comment: True for BIOS, not necessarily true for UEFI. The OP's link is about the latter.